# Using assert in error branch when running cargo test

Tags: rust

I'm reading through the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) and working on part of the [minigrep](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-04-testing-the-librarys-functionality.html) where it asks you to write some unit tests on the `Config::new` function. I'm failing on something that I didn't expect and don't understand why (Google-fu is failing me as well).

This fails

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod new_config_tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_can_create_a_new_config() {
        let expected_query = "expected_qury";
        let expected_filename = "expected_filename.txt";
        let args: Vec<String> = vec!["program/path".to_string(), expected_query.to_string(), expected_filename.to_string()];

        // failing line
        let actual = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| { assert!(false); });
    }
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        if args.len() < 3 {
            return Err("not enough arguments\n");
        }
    
        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();
     
        Ok(Config { query, filename })
    }
}
```

with

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:19:62
   |
19 |         let actual = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| { assert!(false); });
   |                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Config`, found `()`
```

In this test, I'm just making sure that I can create a new `Config` and want it to fail if the `Config::new` function fails. I thought that using `assert` would be correct so that the test framework would handle the failure. If I change the `assert` to `panic`, then the tests pass as expected. Is using panic correct in the above scenario?

Comment: You can also return a `Result` in tests: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/question-mark-in-main-and-tests.html That would allow you to write `let actual = Config::new(&args)?;` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that during type-checking, the compiler doesn't (yet) realize that `assert!(false)` will always fail, so it has to assume that it may pass, resulting in a value of type `()` which is incompatible with the expected `Config` type.

Conversely, if you replace the assert with a call to `panic`, the compiler knows that `panic` never returns, so it doesn't matter if there is no `Config` to return. (Strictly speaking, `panic` typechecks as returning a value of type `!`, aka the "never" type, which is compatible with everything).

IMO you should never use `assert!(false)`, and instead use `panic` when you know that a condition is always fatal. This makes your intent clearer.

Although in this specific case, it would probably be better to assert that the result is `Ok`:

```
assert!(Config::new(&args).is_ok());
```

Comment: Note: the expected output type is `Config`, not a `Result`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I'm still a newb at Rust some some of the stuff mentioned to me is magic but I'll get to learning it eventually.